# Link against non specific version of an assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I'm getting an error like this in an application,

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc889699c44d'
>   or one of its depedencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest defenition does
>   not match the assembly reference.

Which is expected, as this installation happened to have a previous version of the .dll installed.

Can I tell(in Vs2008) to link to this MySQL.data.dll and not care about its version ?
The MYSQL.data.dll reference within the project has a property named "Specific Version", although setting it to false yields no difference.

I'm well aware of the implication if this .dll is binary incompatible with the one required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SpecificVersion can't solve your problem, that only works at compile time.  You ought to rebuild your program for a minimum of surprises.  Or you can use the [`<bindingRedirect>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) in the .exe.config file.

Comment: I'm aware of the surprises that can occur. The question is more general. I'm about to build some assemblies of my own and I want to be able to upgrade those .dlls individually without rebuilding the .exe that reference them

Comment: Don't change the [AssemblyVersion] if it is just a bug fix that doesn't change the public interface of the classes.  Only update the [AssemblyFileVersion].  The .NET 3.5 assemblies are still at 2.0.0.0 for example.  The fact that MySql changed the version is a strong hint that recompiling is required.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can.  Select the referenced dll,  and in the property windows set 'specific version' to False.

Comment: This has no affect at RunTime - only at compile time